# Why ref keyword needs to be initialized and out keyword needn't to be initialized before it is it passed?

Tags: c#, ref, out

Below are the MSDN reference links for the Out keyword and the Ref keyword.

[Out Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

[Ref Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#:%7E:text=The%20ref%20keyword%20indicates%20that,Passing%20an%20argument%20by%20reference.)

Both Ref and Out keywords are pass by reference, then why it is required for one to be initialized and the other needn't to be initialized? Is it something by design convention or is there any other reason/meaning behind the same? Need some help.

Comment: "Is it something by design convention?" Yes. Note also that in the method, `out` parameters must be definitely assigned before the method returns, whereas `ref` parameters needn't be. Does the design make more sense now?

Comment: Simply put: 'in' and 'out' are one-way. 'ref' is two-way, or: 'in' is read-only, 'out' is write-only and 'ref' is read-write.

Comment: Because with `ref` you can pass a value to the called method, ie you can read from it in within the called method. And to be able to read from a variable, it has to be initialized. A `out` variable cannot be read but only set (in fact it has to be set before returning) thus, it doesn't need to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is basically the *Address* part of:
[Address] => points to => [Object]

The ref keyword passes the *address* of an existing object. The method can use the object at that address or instantiate an entirely new one (but at the same address). The address does need to be initialized, even if the value it holds is null. (Below is a little test driver that show this).

The out keyword says that the method must instantiate (or set to null) an *object* (not an address) that it returns.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass = new MyClass(1);

    // Initializing the ADDRESS as an existing object.
    ByRefDemo(ref myClass);
    Console.WriteLine($"Returned value is: {myClass}");

    // Initializing the ADDRESS as a null object.
    myClass = null;
    ByRefDemo(ref myClass);
    Console.WriteLine($"Returned value is: {myClass}");
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public int Value { get; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Value}";

}

void ByRefDemo(ref MyClass addressOf)
{
    var value = addressOf == null ? "NULL" : $"{addressOf}";
    Console.WriteLine($"Incoming value is: {value}" );
    addressOf = new MyClass(2);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at this from the wrong perspective.

`ref` and `out` are both modifiers that are used in a function signature declaration, but they aren't really similar otherwise. They *shouldn't* both do the same thing or have the same requirements.

`ref` tells the compiler that you want a **reference** to something that would ordinarily be passed by value. You are passing a live object. Therefore, you have to already have a live object that you want to pass.

`out` tells the compiler that you want an **output** variable. It acts precisely as another function return value. Just like the function return value, anything assigned to it before the function is called will be overwritten by the value set in the function. So your output variable may be declared and even initialized or set but its value will be overwritten anyway.

You *may* use `ref` to do something similar to `out`, which may be dangerous and may violate best practices or other standards that you're using (it does commonly). Using `out` instead of `ref` won't work though.

Answer (score 0):

There will be occasions when you're programming, that you aren't programming for yourself; you're programming for the benefit of *someone else*. Imagine you're writing some awesome parsing library or something..

There aren't any surprises for someone calling your method if they're passing you some reference type by value semantics; C# makes sure your method gets a copy of their reference. You can modify the contents of the instance at end of the reference, sure, but you can't surprise the caller by swapping out the reference they gave you for something else

It's different with things passed by original reference; they could give you some carefully crafted object that took hours to make and you could trash it by setting the reference to null. It would be nice for them to know this ahead of time, so they could keep their own copy of the reference

As such, with your arguments that are passed by original reference rather than by copy, you have 3 choices with which to decorate them to help indicate your intentions towards their data:

- `out` - "don't bother spending hours crafting the perfect object; I *will* overwrite the reference you give"
- `ref` - "give me some data, but don't be surprised if I replace your object with another. Keep your own reference if you're precious about losing it"
- `in` - "the pass will be done by original reference but I promise I won't swap it out for something else"

The compiler helps you make the first and last promise by insisting that you do set an `out`/don't set an `in`; and this is essentially the answer to your question: in/out/ref behave the way they do *by design* to help you make the promises you make when you use one of them on an argument

`out` and `ref` perhaps don't seem to have much of a point if you're looking at things from "I'm going to write this method here and use it there" but it does help describe to someone else (who cannot see the inner workings of what your method does) what you will do with *their* thing they provide, and that's quite important but easy to overlook if you you don't have that "external caller" perspective in mind